# Visual constraints not being recognized

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, autolayout

I simply want to set constraints which allows the `UIWebView` to fill the screen. (Screen has a `UINavigationbar` and a `UIToolBar`), I've tried following the examples given in the apple documentation but always get a warning and my view doesnt show up. Below is what I've tried.

```
 private func addSubviews(){
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
//        webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

        webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectZero)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        let views = ["myView" : webView]
        let formatString = "|-[myView]-|"
        let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(formatString, options:[] , metrics: nil, views: views)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)
}
```

Comment: Your format string is wrong. You haven't specified the axis for constraint. Should be like `H:|-[myView]-|`. Also this is not enough, you need to apply in vertical direction as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oofh, visual constraints make my head hurt. I never was a fan of the visual language, never made any sense to me. This may be a bit more code but I think it's much easier to read as a developer and far more expressive as to intent.

```
self.view.addSubview(webView)
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

These constraints pin all edges of a view to the respective edge with a distance of 0.

Then at the end of your constraints, don't forget:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

My problem with the visual language is I can't look at it and immediately be clear as to what it does. Here, it's quite explicit. Just for fun, here's a nice function you can use whenever your constant and multiplier is 0:

```
/**
 Adds an edge constraint between the superview and subview with a constant of 0.

 - parameter attribute: Layout attribute.
 - parameter subview:   Subview.
 */
func addEdgeConstraintWithAttribute(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, withSubview subview: UIView) {
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: attribute, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: attribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
```

Used like:

```
self.addEdgeConstraint(.Top, withSubview: webView)
```

where the function is an extension on `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

Im my opinion, your view didn't show up because you didn't set up enough constraints for it.

Basically, with a view, you should add constraints to let it know at least the position and the size. In some cases, you dont need to setup size constraints because that view has `intrinsic content size` like `UILabel`, `UIButton`

Back to your example, you should add constraints like this:

```
private func addSubviews(){
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
    //        webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

    let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectZero)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    let views = ["myView" : webView]
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[myView]-|", options:[] , metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[myView]-|", options:[] , metrics: nil, views: views))
}
```

`H` in `H:|-[myView]-|` stands for horizontal.

`V` in `V:|-[myView]-|` stands for vertical.